# ScrollViewer ScrollToHorizontalOffset strange behaviour

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scrollviewer

I have app which contains `ScrollViewer` and `StackPanel`.

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfScrollViewer.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="800" Loaded="MainWindow_OnLoaded">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Blue" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="MyScrollViewer" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <StackPanel x:Name="MyStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ScrollViewer>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="left" Click="LeftButton_Click" />
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="right" Click="RightButton_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Inside `StackPanel` I create several `Rectangle`s from code behind and their width is calculated from width of my `Window`.

**CODE BEHIND:**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfScrollViewer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private double _scrollWidth;
        private double _edgeScrollWidth;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void LeftButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var offset = MyScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset;
            if (offset == MyScrollViewer.ScrollableWidth)
            {
                MyScrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(offset - _edgeScrollWidth);
            }
            else
            {
                MyScrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(offset - _scrollWidth);
            }
        }

        private void RightButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var offset = MyScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset;
            if (offset == 0)
            {
                MyScrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(offset + _edgeScrollWidth);
            }
            else
            {
                MyScrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(offset + _scrollWidth);
            }
        }

        private void MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _scrollWidth = Width - 60;
            _edgeScrollWidth = Width - 90;
            var itemWidth = Width - 80;

            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                MyStackPanel.Children.Add(new Rectangle { Width = itemWidth });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I press the right `Button` my rectangles looks like this:
[image: wrong offset]
But I want to see equal parts of the rectangles on the sides. I want to have my whole rectangle centered which it is not. I really think that I calculated offset correctly so I really don't know where I did mistake.
Am I missing something or is there some problems with calculating with `WPF`s independent units?

Comment: Are you going to allow your window to be resizeable? If so, it won't be possible to centre your first and last rectangles. You can see for yourself by making the window wider: there's no way that you can drag the scrollbar to make the first rectangle centred.

Comment: No my window wouldn't be resizable. It will have fixed size defined during creation. I don't want to center my first and last rectangles either but I want to center the rest of my rectangles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem stems I think from using the `Width` property in the `Loaded` event handler. `Width` here is the width property of the `Window` class, and the value of that property *includes the width of the window's borders*. What you actually want is the width of the internal part of the window, or the *client area*. There is no WPF property for this, so you need to take the `ActualWidth` of the window's child element (the window's `Content`).

Also, I'd recommend getting rid of the "magic" numbers by converting them to constants.

The following is a re-jigged version of your code that should do what you want:

```
const double RectangleMarginThickness = 10;
const double RectangleWidthReduction = 80;  // Rect width is client width less this
const double PaddingToCenter = RectangleWidthReduction/2 - RectangleMarginThickness;

double _rectangleWidthIncludingMargin;

private void MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    double clientWidth = (Content as FrameworkElement).ActualWidth;
    var itemWidth = clientWidth - RectangleWidthReduction;
    _rectangleWidthIncludingMargin = itemWidth + (RectangleMarginThickness * 2);

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        MyStackPanel.Children.Add(new Rectangle { Width = itemWidth });
    }
}

private void LeftButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SetNewHorizontalOffset(childOffset: -1);
}

private void RightButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SetNewHorizontalOffset(childOffset: 1);
}

private void SetNewHorizontalOffset(int childOffset)
{
    double offset = MyScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset + PaddingToCenter;

    if (_rectangleWidthIncludingMargin > 0)
    {
        int currentChildIndex;
        if (childOffset < 0)
        {
            currentChildIndex =
                (int) Math.Ceiling(offset / _rectangleWidthIncludingMargin);
        }
        else
        {
            currentChildIndex =
                (int) Math.Floor(offset / _rectangleWidthIncludingMargin);
        }

        int newChildIndex = CoerceToRange(currentChildIndex + childOffset,
            0, MyStackPanel.Children.Count - 1);
        offset = newChildIndex * _rectangleWidthIncludingMargin - PaddingToCenter;
    }

    MyScrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(offset);
}

private static int CoerceToRange(int value, int minimum, int maximum)
{
    return Math.Max(minimum, Math.Min(value, maximum));
}
```

Comment: It seems that it is working properly. My problem was that I use `WindowStyle="None"` and I thought that `Width` is same as yours `ActualWidth`. Thanks I am smarter now.